Upgrade from 20.04.4 LTS to 22.04 Fails
Running do-release-upgrade fails with a log of
    2024-06-01 08:32:52,160 DEBUG Upgradable, but held- back: 
2024-06-01 08:32:52,160 DEBUG Remove: 
2024-06-01 08:32:52,160 DEBUG Install: 
2024-06-01 08:32:52,160 DEBUG Upgrade: 
2024-06-01 08:32:52,165 DEBUG apt btrfs snapshots supported: False
2024-06-01 08:32:52,165 DEBUG cache aufs_rw_dir: /tmp/
2024-06-01 08:32:52,166 DEBUG Free space on /: 54596825088
2024-06-01 08:32:52,166 DEBUG Dir /usr mounted on /
2024-06-01 08:32:52,166 DEBUG Dir /var mounted on /
2024-06-01 08:32:52,166 DEBUG Dir /boot mounted on /
2024-06-01 08:32:52,166 DEBUG Dir /var/cache/apt/archives mounted on /
2024-06-01 08:32:52,166 DEBUG Free space on /tmp: 937246720
2024-06-01 08:32:52,166 DEBUG Dir /home mounted on /
2024-06-01 08:32:52,166 DEBUG Dir /tmp mounted on /tmp
2024-06-01 08:32:52,166 DEBUG fs_free contains: '{'/': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f0570bf2a10>, '/usr': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f0570bf2a10>, '/var': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f0570bf2a10>, '/boot': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f0570bf2a10>, '/var/cache/apt/archives': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f0570bf2a10>, '/tmp': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f0570bf0c10>, '/home': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f0570bf2a10>}'
2024-06-01 08:32:52,516 DEBUG dir '/var/cache/apt/archives' needs '0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f0570bf2a10>' (54596825088.000000)
2024-06-01 08:32:52,516 DEBUG dir '/usr' needs '0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f0570bf2a10>' (54596825088.000000)
2024-06-01 08:32:52,516 DEBUG dir '/var' needs '0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f0570bf2a10>' (54596825088.000000)
2024-06-01 08:32:52,516 DEBUG dir '/usr' needs '52428800' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f0570bf2a10>' (54596825088.000000)
2024-06-01 08:32:52,516 DEBUG dir '/boot' needs '116071445.7' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f0570bf2a10>' (54544396288.000000)
2024-06-01 08:32:52,516 DEBUG dir '/tmp' needs '5242880' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f0570bf0c10>' (937246720.000000)
2024-06-01 08:32:52,516 DEBUG dir '/' needs '10485760' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f0570bf2a10>' (54428324842.300003)
2024-06-01 08:32:52,516 DEBUG dir '/tmp' needs '0.0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f0570bf0c10>' (932003840.000000)
2024-06-01 08:32:52,516 DEBUG dir '/usr' needs '0.0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f0570bf2a10>' (54417839082.300003)
2024-06-01 08:32:52,516 DEBUG Not an UEFI system
2024-06-01 08:32:52,518 DEBUG demoted: 'g++-9 libffi7 libstdc++-9-dev ruby-minitest ruby-power-assert ruby-test-unit'
2024-06-01 08:32:52,518 DEBUG found components: {'jammy': {'main', 'restricted', 'multiverse', 'universe'}, 'jammy-updates': {'main', 'restricted', 'multiverse', 'universe'}, 'jammy-security': {'main', 'restricted', 'multiverse', 'universe'}}
2024-06-01 08:32:52,518 DEBUG abort called
2024-06-01 08:32:52,520 DEBUG openCache()
2024-06-01 08:32:55,120 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-107 with 
2024-06-01 08:32:55,121 DEBUG Comparing 5.4.0-182 with 5.15.0-107
2024-06-01 08:32:55,278 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 84463

Tried looking around and unninstalled "snapd", "screen" with no luck.
apt update is good
apt upgrade is good
No held back packages.
Not sure what else to do, anyone came across this? Thanks in advance.
Edit: Has active cPanel installation, initialy when i tried to do-release-upgrade i was greeted with a:
This usually is caused by a system where /tmp is mounted noexec. Please remount without noexec and run the upgrade again.

I used sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmpto solve that issue.

There are quite a few people that have upgraded and eventually had to reinstall, may be it is better if you consider doing that. Use the USB and try Ubuntu before you do anything, see if all your hardware is supported and everything incl. sound. network and grafics work,

is there anyway to specify a target do-release-upgrade to 21.04?

20.04.4 LTS, apologies.

If you're actually running 20.04 LTS ensure you've applied all security fixes, as 20.04.4 implies you haven't since back in 2022!  (Refer https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/ which shows the ISO release date of 20.04.5, but installed systems upgraded to 20.04.5 before the ISO release date).. An updated system currently reports as 20.04.6 but if yours is still reporting as 20.04.4 then you're not using Ubuntu (Ubuntu based maybe thus issues) OR something vital is wrong with your system...

console states: Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-182-generic x86_64)
